# how to align multiple div's next to each other?

Tags: html, css

I am new to Html,I'm trying to align multiple div's next to each other horizontally. i tried float property and display inline property also, but nothing works correctly.can anyone suggest any methods for it?

my code:

```
#display2letter
{
width:150px;
height:50px;
background-color:grey;
box: 10px 10px 5px #888888;    
}
#display3letter
{
width:150px;
height:50px;
background-color:blue;
box: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}
#display4letter
{
width:150px;
height:50px;
background-color:grey;
box: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}

#one
{
position:fixed;
left:23%;
}
#two
{
position:fixed;
left:23%;
}
#three
{
position:fixed;
left:23%;
}
```

here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/pGHS9/1/

Comment: Can you be more specific, what to be aligned and where?

Comment: i need to align those three output divs horizontally.

Comment: the three boxes are aligned vertically,i need to align those horizontally next to each other..

Comment: what about the images??

Comment: yeah they also have to be aligned.

Comment: @VladislavStanic: your previous answer is working,why u deleted that answer ?

Comment: I thought that was wrong so deleted it, I undeleted it now, if there need to be some corrections please tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made JSFIDDLE, I am not sure if that is what you ment.

I added a box and changed position fixed to relative:

```
.box {
    float: left;
    width: 270px;
}
#one
{
position:relative;
left:23%;
}
#two
{
position:relative;
left:23%;
}
#three
{
position:relative;
left:23%;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pGHS9/11/)

Answer (score 1):

The more recommended solutions is place the container with display: inline-block and percent the blocks.

Something Like this:

html

```
<div class="horizontal">
other elements
</div><div class="horizontal">
other elements
</div>
```

css

```
.horizontal {
  display:inline-block;
  width: 33%;
}
```

This solutions is responsive design implementation.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<div id="first">first</div>
<div id="second">second</div>
```

then

```
#first{
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    border:1px solid green;
}
#second{
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

here's the JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/PdXk5/

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this....

<div>
   <div class="inner">first div</div>
    <div class="inner">second div</div>
    <div class="inner">third div</div>
</div>
div{
    border:1px dashed #000;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}
div.inner{
    border:1px solid black;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin:5px;
}
```